# Loosing b2Body from a b2MouseJoint

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have created a mallet, and made a b2MouseJoint to drag mallet, like this:

```
if (_playerBuckFixture->TestPoint(locationWorld)) {
    b2MouseJointDef md;
    md.bodyA = _groundBody;
    md.bodyB = _playerBuckBody;
    md.target = locationWorld;
    md.collideConnected = true;
    md.dampingRatio = 0.0f;
    md.frequencyHz = 60.0;
    md.maxForce = powl(_playerBuckBody->GetMass()+10,37);

    _mouseJoint = (b2MouseJoint *)_world->CreateJoint(&md);
    _playerBuckBody->SetAwake(true);
}
```

but when i move my finger fast, mallet use to loose grip from my finger, and follow my finger not as fast as my finger moves.

Please give me good suggestion to improve b2MouseJoint grip.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Touch locations when moving a finger fast can be very far apart. You may need to interpolate between touch location and the previous one.